# Oracle PeopleSoft CRM pre-built VM Template

Tags: oracle, peoplesoft

Am looking for a pre-built VM Template of Oracle PeopleSoft CRM.. In the [instructions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/vm/peoplesoftcrm-170419.html) it says:

> Visit http://edelivery.oracle.com/oraclevm 
>   Complete your registration information (Name, Company Name, Email Address and Country) and click on the download agreement 
>   Select "Oracle VM Templates" from the "Select a Product Pack" pull-down menu 
>   Select "x86 64 bit" from the "Platform" pull-down menu 
>   Click "Go" and then select from the list of Oracle VM Templates 
>   Download and unzip the files and read the readme

But I can't find PeopleSoft listed in after hitting the "Go" button!

Is there any other way to download it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In the past, the pre-built vm's have required a support contract and could be downloaded from the https://support.oracle.com site.